# get step only from sensor using google fit api

Tags: android, google-fit

I want to get step value using google fit api and tried the example provided by google [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistoryApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistoryapi/MainActivity.java). I could successfully implemented it and am able to retrieve history data (both today data and past data).

However, if I insert step value (from insert activity) manually to fit app, or integrated third party apps to the fit app, it will take all the step value (it will get the same value as what fit app shows).

I don't want the step value from user input neither from the third app.
Is it possible to separate the step value based on the data source if we use fit API.
*in [fit FAQ page](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq) , it is written:

> How do I query for available third-party or other data sources?
>   Today, this is only available via the REST API; this data is not yet available via the Android API.

so does it mean, we can not query the data from the sensor only?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)